# Date validator on DatePicker trigger false negatives in IE7/IE8

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have some basic validation on a form which includes two jQuery UI DatePickers. The format of the date is yy-mm-dd. There is a *required* and *date* validation on both DatePickers.

These work as expected in Chrome & FF, but trigger false negatives (valid input is said to be invalid) in IE7/IE8.

Date picker setup:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

This is unrelated but I figured I would include, just in case:

```
$.validator.addMethod("endDate", function(value, element) {
    var startDate = $('#startDate').val();
    return Date.parse(startDate) <= Date.parse(value);
});
```

The actual validation:

```
$('#ExampleForm').validate({
    rules: {    
        StartDate: {
            required: true,
            date: true
        },
        EndDate: {
            required: true,
            date: true,
            endDate: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        StartDate: {
            required: "Start Date required",
            date: "Invalid date. Must be formatted yyyy-mm-dd"
        },
        EndDate: {
            required: "End Date required",
            date: "Invalid date. Must be formatted yyyy-mm-dd",
            endDate: "Start date must occur before end date."
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo(element.parent().next());
    },
    submitHandle: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

In IE7/IE8, valid input (just picking a date) with both DatePickers will result in the *date* error ("Invalid date. Must be formatted yyyy-mm-dd"). This does not occur in other browsers.

It also doesn't produce any Javascript errors.

Thanks in advance,

Ian

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`dateISO`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/dateISO) option:

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        StartDate: {
            required: true,
            dateISO: true
        },
        EndDate: {
            required: true,
            dateISO: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        StartDate: {
            required: "Start Date required",
            dateISO: "Invalid date. Must be formatted yyyy-mm-dd"
        },
        EndDate: {
            required: "End Date required",
            dateISO: "Invalid date. Must be formatted yyyy-mm-dd"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

IE won't parse dates in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, which is why using regular `date` fails in IE.  I believe jQuery validate just uses `Date.parse` or `new Date(dateString)` to check for validity.  To check this, try doing `new Date("1987-11-14")` and alerting the value in IE and FF.  You'll get `NaN` in IE and a date object in FF.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/QqSrJ/2/

Answer (score 3):

Example to overcome IE NaN

```
var startDate   = "1987-11-14";
startDate       = startDate.split("-");
startDate       = new Date(startDate[0], + startDate[1], startDate[2]);
alert(startDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Send the date how you need it formatted to a hidden field in your form using `altField` and `altFormat`, this fixed my NaN errors.

```
$("#selectorDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    altField: "#another_field_date",
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem in my own code, where the date format was the same as described above and the form in the JSP (with a little assistance from Spring's form tags) looked like this:

```
<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" value="${user.dateOfBirth}" var="dob"/>
<form:input id="date-of-birth" type="date" path="dateOfBirth" value="${dob}"/>
```

The problem was the the date field is optional (required=false in JQuery validation rules), but it used DatePicker, and was thus validated automatically when it was filled. The problem was that on all browsers, and on IE9 (and up) it validated correctly, but on IE8, it caused an "invalid date" validation stop.

I played with the jquery validation rules, I tried using dateISO (though I am by no means saying that this solution will not work for some), to no avail.

Turns out that in my case, all I had to do was remove the attribute 'type="date"'. Now the date validates properly, and remains an optional field.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the class="date" attribute (not type="date") on the input field was causing validator to automatically add date validation to the field, which triggered the false negative in IE8. So I changed the class to 'date-select', then used the dateISO rule as in Andrew Whitaker's answer.